# Как извлечь модель со всеми связями в виде таблицы пригодной для отображения клиенту в браузере?

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, eloquent

Есть таблица заказов. Она связан с таблицей - Покупатели и таблицей - Услуги. Извлекая модель со связями на выходе я получаю json массив вида:

```
[
  {
    "id": 8,
    "service_id": 3,
    "customer_id": 8,
    "date": "29.05.2017",
    "time": "11:00:00",
    "created_at": "2017-05-11 21:59:49",
    "updated_at": "2017-05-11 21:59:49",
    "deleted_at": null
  },

...
]
```

Как сделать так что бы вместо ключей указанных в модели, а лучше наверное просто дополнительно к уже существующим полям в извлеченных объектах присутствовали поля связанных моделей. Например:

```
  [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "service_id": 3,

        "service_name": "укладка" //

        "customer_id": 8,

        "customer_name": "Евгений", //
        "customer_phone":"05022222288", //

        "date": "29.05.2017",
        "time": "11:00:00",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 21:59:49",
        "updated_at": "2017-05-11 21:59:49",
        "deleted_at": null
      },

 ...
]
```

или

```
  [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "service":{
             "name":"укладка" //
        },
        "customer":{
             "name": "Евгений", //
             "phone":"05022222288", //
        },
        "date": "29.05.2017",
        "time": "11:00:00",
        "created_at": "2017-05-11 21:59:49",
        "updated_at": "2017-05-11 21:59:49",
        "deleted_at": null
      },
```

Другими словами, я хочу что бы в извлеченной из БД модели имеющей связи, сразу присутствовали данные из других таблиц с содержимым их полей (не просто голые айдишники в виде внешних ключей). Нужно получить таблицу которую можно удобно отобразить в браузере.

Единственный способ достичь желаемого результата, это JOIN-ы? Есть ли в Ларавел готовое решение генерирующее таблицу в нужном для меня виде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вариант использовать метод `with`, тогда он будет сразу подтягивать ещё и реляционную таблицу, то есть если к примеру у вас модель называется `Order` и модели `Service` и `Customer` вы хотите получить в объекте `Order` напишите следующее:

```
$order = Order::with('service', 'customer')->find(8);
```

Если реляции у вас называются как в моем примере, тогда в объекте `Order` в методе `relations` вы будете получать объект `Service` и `Customer` и через `$order->service` и `$order->customer` будете получать данные.

Да, вы не получите его как планировали в методе `attributes`, но они у вас сразу будут в объекте, чтобы их туда добавить можно использовать [мутаторы](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) на все поля, и тогда сможете сделать аттрибуты customer_name и т.д., но лучше так не делать, а брать данные через реляцию.

Comment: Решение, с использованием метода with(). Помогло. Как результат, получен json объект включающий в себя объекты 'service', 'customer'. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Почитай что такое [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/) и [GraphQL](https://learngraphql.com/basics/introduction), соответственно есть пакеты для Laravel : spatie/laravel-fractal и Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql

Я ни в коем случае не говорю, что ответ Yaroslav Molchan не верный, я просто пытаюсь дополнить ответ возможными вариантами!

В чем вся прелесть таких подходов:

1. Вы можете создать несколько представлений, которые будете отдавать в зависимости от прав доступа
2. Представление будут содержать ту информацию которая необходима для данной страницы (запроса)
3. Представление будет того формата который вам нужен, без лишних полей
4. Также я считаю это поможет вам сделать единый формат ответа

Есть еще всякие плюшки которые могут быть полезны такие как версионность API или кэширование ответов и как очень не мало важный факт :) ну мало ли, в принципе вы не сильно привязываетесь к фреймворку или Eloquent